# Odd transparency effect when merging two .png's with transparency in PHP-GD

Tags: php, png, gd, alphablending

Merging two images with transparent sections produces the following composite image:

[image]

I'm wondering why the transparent section of the image I've overlayed onto the green background shows up as such? Anyone?

```
$base = imagecreatefrompng('application/assets/images/vel1_bg.png');
        imagealphablending($base, false);
        imagesavealpha($base, true);
        list($baseWidth, $baseHeight, $type, $attr) = getimagesize('application/assets/images/vel1_bg.png');

        $user_board_items = $this->config->item('user_board_items');

        foreach($array as $key => $value){
            $item = imagecreatefrompng('application/assets/images/items/' . $user_board_items[$value[0]] . '.png'); 
            imagealphablending($item, false);
            imagesavealpha($item, true);    
            list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize('application/assets/images/items/'. $user_board_items[$value[0]] . '.png');

            imagecopyresampled($base,
                        $item,
                        floor(($value[1] / 100) * $baseWidth),
                        floor(($value[2] / 100) * $baseHeight),
                        0,
                        0,
                        $width,
                        $height,
                        $width,
                        $height);

            imagedestroy($item);
        }

        //We have to capture the output buffer
        ob_start();
        imagepng($base);
        $baseimg = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: Can you provide links to the original files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP GD merging png images with transparencies help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495903/php-gd-merging-png-images-with-transparencies-help)

Comment: nope, not a duplicate. Look at the code I'm using different merge functions.

Comment: @Casey: it's the same basic question. All you've done is switching from a Brand X tool to using Brand Y. The core question remains the same.

Comment: http://www.messageamplify.com/projects/velcro/application/assets/images/items/Cheese.png

Comment: http://www.messageamplify.com/projects/velcro/application/assets/images/vel1_bg.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GD does not support transparency in 32-bit PNG. You have to use either 8-bit with one transparent 'color' or 24-bit (officially 24-bit does not support transparency, but Photoshop can do it when using 'save for web' with 24bit png).